# Web-based equivalent of OpenOffice.org Base or Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, openoffice.org

I've currently been using Base/MS Access to create forms etc. that interface with a backend database, to save me writing a backend in PHP. Downside is that it only runs on the desktop. Is anyone aware of any web-based equivalent?

Edit: Should have done more research, I need it to interact with MySQL, not an Access DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered Access 2010 : [Hosting an Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879281/hosting-an-access-db/2882623#2882623)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Access version, you could use Data Access Pages (Can be used with Access 2007+ with some additional work.). The recommended usage for 2007+ would be within SharePoint.

Comment: Data Access Pages have long since fallen into disuse, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure Data Access Pages were ever really in use.