# Differences between Access-VBA 2010 and 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Are there many differences between Access VBA 2010 and 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179181.aspx#BKMK_WhatsNew)**

**What’s new**

- Share a database on the Web
- Export to .pdf and .xps
- Connect to a Web service as an external data source
- Backstage view

**What’s changed**

- Backward compatibility between Access 2010 and Access 2007
- Enhanced security
- Support for SQL Server 2008 data types

**What’s removed**

- Calendar control (mscal.ocx)
- Microsoft Replication Conflict Viewer
- Snapshot file format
- Data access pages
- Lotus 1-2-3, Paradox, Jet2.x, and Red2 IISAM

**In Addition**

There are a lot of view options for objects, including custom views. Probably the most interesting new developments are:

- Closer integration with Sharepoint and web development. From Albert D Kallal:

> Here is a video of an application I
>   wrote in access 2010. Note how at the
>   half way I run the same application
>   including the Access forms in a
>   standard web browser. This application
>   was built 100% inside of the Access
>   client. The end result needs no
>   ActiveX or Silverlight to run.
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

-- [Hosting an Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879281/hosting-an-access-db/2882623#2882623)

- Access 2010 data macros (similar to triggers)

> A key concept about data macros is
>   they don’t have any UI. You can call
>   Named data macros passing parameters
>   from a UI macro but data macro can’t
>   open a form or invoke a message box.
>   They return errors that UI macros can
>   catch and display to the user. These
>   errors are also logged to the
>   UsysApplicationLog table. This is a
>   special table that keeps a history of
>   data macro failures and other useful
>   debug information you choose to write
>   to it.

-- http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx

Comment: So the short answer to the question (about VBA, not all of Access), is "Not really...".